# Method .includes() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, function, methods, include, typeerror

I am studying through Eloquent Javascript, and I have the following code as one of the exercices.

```
class Group {
constructor(){
    this.arr = []
}

add(value){
    if(!this.has(value)) {
        this.arr = this.arr.push(value)
    }
}

has(value){
    return this.arr.includes(value);
}

delete(value){
    this.arr = this.arr.filter(n => n !== value)
}

static from(collection){
    let rec = new Group;
    for (let value of collection){
        rec.add(value)
        }
return rec
    }
}
```

It seems right and it should be working but I get the error

> TypeError: arr.includes is not a function

What is that about? I can't find the answer.

Comment: Try to change your "has" method to an array function

Comment: Which browser/version of JS are you using? See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes for compatibility

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push),

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

Hence, the problem is with this line.  `this.arr` is no longer an array after this line.

```
this.arr = this.arr.push(value)
```

So, update this to following

```
this.arr.push(value)
```

Comment: Thank you, the arr variable became a number, of course!!

Comment: @Zhast - Glad to help you!